# How to update a element in List collection in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List collection
like `List<clsTest> objList = new List<clsTest>();`

It has around hundred columns.

```
Predicate<ScreenDefinition> linqQuery = new Predicate<ScreenDefinition>(objQuery);
index = tmp.FindIndex(objQuery);
```

*objQuery is query for conditions*

**I tried like for update**

```
listJoinedScreenDefinition[index].fieldName = "update";
```

But prob is i need to genrate **'fieldName'** dynamically according to my logic.

```
Say "seat" + 05 => seat05 is the column name.
```

Like wise **seat1  - seat 100** are there.

In every iteration i need to update only one column.

in the way i tried how to pass the dynamically column name in that List ?

I am new to .Net and Linq.

Please suggest some way to achieve this..

Comment: "It has around hundred columns.".. What???

Comment: he meant "about" @Euphoric

Comment: @LiranElisha That still doesn't make any sense. Just as rest of his question.

Comment: Sorry if i confuse you.Please explain what u didn't understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question has nothing to do with lists and queries. You would be in the same situation if you had only one instance of your `clsTest` class. The problem is with the design of the class.

If I understand you correctly, `clsTest` has 100 members, with names like `seat1`, `seat2`, `seat50`, etc, is that correct? If so, that's a pretty bad class design, as you've found out, because it requires you to hardcode all references to specific fields inn your code, or alternately use reflection (as Garath suggested in his answer) which is is more complicated and error prone.

A better solution would be to redesign your `clsTest` class to have a property called `Seats` which is an `Array` or `List` of seats. If you have a `public List<string> Seats {get;set;}`, you can access `myObject.Seats[5]` to get to the fifth seat.

Of course, if it's more than just a list of seats, and you can have several different types of numbered properties ("seat" + "05" and "row" + "02", for instance), you can use a `Dictionary<string, string>`, to map between "seat05" and its value.

Comment: Yeah this is fine.I stick to the collection structure from mongodb and proceeding with those objects.
actually collection struture is like that with 100 columns..
that part is not my hand.
I cant change that.

But this way is cleaner and better.
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to using reflection. I do not know if you are using properties or fields.
For properties code will look like:

```
var target = listJoinedScreenDefinition[index];
Type type = target.GetType();
PropertyInfo prop = type.GetProperty("propertyName");
prop.SetValue (target, propertyValue, null);
```

For fields code is very similar:

```
var target = listJoinedScreenDefinition[index];
FieldInfo fi = target.GetType().GetField("Name", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
fi.SetValue(target ,value)
```